# Migrating GAE search to elastic cloud

Tags: google-app-engine

How GAE search documents can be migrated to elastic cloud.

1. Indexes
2. namespaces
3. Also how going forward, changes in datastore can be automatically synced to elastic cloud

Not getting option to export the search api docs to import to elastic cloud.
Not getting any good plugin to sync data from data store to elastic cloud going forward